# Check mySQL version on Mac 10.8.5

Tags: mysql, macos, version, osx-snow-leopard

How can I check (step-by-step ) the version of mySQL installed on my Mac 10.8.5?

I tried using command prompt, but couldn't figure out.

Comment: question tagged as [tag:osx-snow-leopard]? Mac 10.8.x = Mountain Lion. hehe. just saying.

Answer (score 45):

Every time you used the mysql console, the version is shown.

```
 mysql -u user
```

Successful console login shows the following which includes the mysql server version.

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1432
Server version: 5.5.9-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

---

You can also check the mysql server version directly by executing the following command:

```
mysql --version
```

---

You may also check the version information from the mysql console itself using the version variables:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Output will be something like this:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| innodb_version          | 1.1.5               |
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| slave_type_conversions  |                     |
| version                 | 5.5.9-log           |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | i386                |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.4             |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

You may also use this:

```
mysql> select @@version;
```

---

The STATUS command display version information as well.

```
mysql> STATUS
```

---

You can also check the version by executing this command:

```
mysql -v
```

It's worth mentioning that if you have encountered something like this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

you can fix it by:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 13):

To check your MySQL version on your mac, navigate to the directory where you installed it (default is **usr/local/mysql/bin**) and issue this command:

```
./mysql --version
```

Alternatively, to avoid needing to navigate to that specific dir to run the command, add its location to your path ($PATH). There's more than one way to add a dir to your $PATH (with explanations on stackoverflow and other places on how to do so), [such as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx) adding it to your ./bash_profile.

After adding the mysql bin dir to your $PATH, verify it's there by executing:

```
echo $PATH
```

Thereafter you can check your mysql version from anywhere by running (note no "./"):

```
mysql --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just call `mysql` command with `--version` option.

```
mysql --version
```