# How do I edit $PATH (.bash_profile) on OS X?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, path, osx-yosemite

I am trying to edit an entry to PATH, as I did something wrong.

I am using [Mac OS X v10.10.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite)

I have tried:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

But the file editor opens with nothing inside.

My problem:

I am trying to install ANDROID_HOME to my PATH

I misspelled it, but when I closed the terminal and went back it was gone, so I tried again:

> ```
> export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
> export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
> ```

This time, I typed the command correctly but, when I closed the terminal, my settings disappeared again.

How do I execute my desired settings?

If I was to edit bash.profile, how would I enter the above code?

Comment: Use `vi ~/.bash_profile` or `subl ~/.bash_profile` or `mate ~/.bash_profile`, depending on your favourite editor.

Comment: just tried nano ~/.bash_profile, it loads, but there is nothing inside

Comment: Sounds like `.bash_profile` is empty/missing then.

Comment: For newbies like, these notes will help: 1. `~/.bash_profile` means it's located in the **root** directory. `~` means root directory. 2. files prefixed with `.` are invisible to `ls` command. They are _kind of_ like hidden files, files the normal user doesn't really need to see. Our case here is an exception. To be able to see it you can do `ls -a` 3. `touch` will create a file at the specified directory _if_ it doesn't exist. It it does exist then nothing will happen

Comment: 4. and obviously `open` will open it with your default texteditor. 5. As a result doing `touch ~/.bash_profile` from **any directory** will work. because your path is not relative

Comment: @Honey: `~` means home (*i.e.*, `$HOME`), not root (*i.e.*, `/`).

Answer (score 508, accepted):

You have to open that file with a text editor and then save it.

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

It will open the file with [TextEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit), paste your things and then save it. If you open it again you'll find your edits.

You can use other editors:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
mate ~/.bash_profile
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

But if you don't know how to use them, it's easier to use the `open` approach.

---

Alternatively, you can rely on `pbpaste`. Copy

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

in the system clipboard and then in a shell run

```
pbpaste > ~/.bash_profile
```

---

Or alternatively you can also use `cat`

```
cat > ~/.bash_profile
```

(now `cat` waits for input: paste the two export definitions and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>).

Comment: There are issues using things like `cat` to write to files when the text contains references to environment variables as it means those references need to be escaped.  It's must more usual to use a text editor.

Comment: What would it mean if I enter "touch ./bash_profile" (it says nothing) then "open .bash_profile" and it tells me that file does not exist?

Comment: if you are using Catalina, follow the steps outlined below : https://mkyong.com/maven/install-maven-on-mac-osx/#install-maven-manually

Comment: Replace `bash_profile` with `zshrc` from this answer

Comment: getting an empty file using all methods . ??

Comment: @user2568374 if you have never edited this file before, it will be empty. Just add what you need

Comment: `nano ~/.bash_profile` helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 136):

#### A bit more detailed for beginners

---

Before you begin with `.bash_profile` on Mac, please be aware that since macOS Catalina [Zsh (z shell)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) is the default shell. Therefore stuff we used to put in the `.bash_profile` now belongs to the `.zshenv` or the `.zshrc` file.

#### Note about `.zshenv` and `.zshrc`  ([*source*](https://carlosroso.com/the-right-way-to-migrate-your-bash-profile-to-zsh/))

- `.zshenv`: invocations of the shell. Often contains exported
  variables that should be available to other programs. For example,
  $PATH.
- `.zshrc`: Sourced in interactive shells only. It should contain
  commands to set up aliases, functions, options, key bindings, etc.

---

### STEP 1

Make sure the `.bash_profile` file exists (or the `.zshenv` of course). Remember that the `.bash_profile` file isn't there by default. You have to create it on your own.

Go into your **user folder in finder**.
The .bash_profile file should be findable there.
-> **HD/Users/[USERNAME]**

Remember: Files with a point at the beginning **'.' are hidden** by default.

To show *hidden files* in macOS Finder:

- Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

If it's not existing, **you have to create `.bash_profile`** on your own.

**Open terminal** app and switch into **user folder** with simple command:

```
cd
```

If it's not existing, use this **command to create the file**:

```
touch .bash_profile
```

### STEP 2

If you can't memorise the nerdy commands for save and close in vim, nano etc (the way recommended above) the easiest way to edit is to open `.bash_profile` (or the `.zshenv`) file in your favored code editor (Sublime Text, Visual Studio Code, BBEdit etc.).

Finder -> User folder. Right click -> Open With : Visual Studio Code (or other code editor). Or drag it on app in dock. And there you can edit it, pass export commands in new lines.

Comment: I've personally found accessing "hidden" files normally to be a plus with emacs...

Comment: I updated the way, to show hidden files in Mac OS's Finder.
Press: Command + Shift + .

Comment: For some reason, touch did not create the file, but I used cat to do it as in Alessandro's answer.

Comment: In other words, what you want to do now is `touch ~/.zshrc; open ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 85):

If you are using [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina), you need to update the *.zshrc* file instead of file *.bash_profile* or *.profile*.

Comment: Wow, i've been going crazy trying to figure out why i can't update bundler and why my system is looking for the wrong path for ruby. Should i copy paste my bash_profile to zshrc?

Comment: Im using catalina, but I dont find that file, can you explain what is the directory ?

Comment: WTF, this is crazyness!

Comment: You need to make sure your terminal is now zsh with `chsh -s /bin/zsh`. That will activate your terminal to automatically be zsh. Then you can make changes in ~/.zshrc or ~/.zprofile.

Comment: THANK YOU.
If you don't want to type everything again, you can simply do:
`mv .bash_profile .zshrc`

Answer (score 25):

For **Mac OS**, step by step:

1. First of all, open a terminal and write it: `cd ~/`
2. Create your Bash file: `touch .bash_profile`

   You created your ".bash_profile" file, but if you would like to edit it, continue reading with step 3.
3. Edit your Bash profile: `open -e .bash_profile`

   After that you can save from the top-left corner of screen: *File* → *Save*
4. Done!

Comment: `touch ~/.bash_profile` solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Set the path *JAVA_HOME* and *ANDROID_HOME*. You have to open terminal and enter the below cmd.

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

After that, paste the below paths in the base profile file and save it:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk 
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Re "base profile file": Do you mean "the Bash *.profile* file"?

Answer (score 10):

For beginners: To create your `.bash_profile` file in your home directory on macOS, run:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can paste in the following:

https://gist.github.com/mocon/0baf15e62163a07cb957888559d1b054

As you can see, it includes some example aliases and an environment variable at the bottom.

One you're done making your changes, follow the instructions at the bottom of the [Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) editor window to WriteOut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) and Exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>). Then quit your `Terminal` and reopen it, and you will be able to use your newly defined aliases and environment variables.

Answer (score 8):

Just type `open ~/.bash_profile` on terminal, you can edit it.

Answer (score 5):

Determine which shell you're using by typing `echo $SHELL` in Terminal.

Then open/create correct rc file. For Bash it's `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`. For Z shell it's `$HOME/.zshrc`.

Add this line to the file end:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/your/new/path"
```

To verify, refresh variables by restarting Terminal or typing `source $HOME/.<rc file>` and then do `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X doesn't store the path in file *.bash_profile*, but file *.profile*, since Mac OS X is a branch of the [*BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) family. You should be able to see the export blah blah blah in file *.profile* once you do `cat .profile` on your terminal.

Comment: As of Yosemite (10.10) this is no longer true, if it ever was.  Bash has been the default shell on macOS for a long time already.  Historically, *BSD had `csh` which is incompatible, and uses `.cshrc` and not `.profile` (though if you need to use several Bourne-compatible shells, it makes sense to have common settings in `.profile`).

Answer (score 2):

For me, my macOS is [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave). And I was facing the same issue for three days and in the end, I just wrote the correct path in the *.bash_profile* file which was like this:

```
export PATH=/Users/[YOURNAME]/development/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

- Note 1: if you don't have filr *.bash_profile*, create one and write the line above
- Note 2: zip your downloaded Flutter SDK in `[home]/development` if you copy and paste this path

Comment: This.
Also make sure to close the terminal and open a new one to see flutter commands work

Answer (score 2):

***The simplest answer is:***

**Step 1:** Fire up Terminal.app

**Step 2:** Type nano .bash_profile – This command will open the .bash_profile document (or create it if it doesn’t already exist) in the easiest-to-use text editor in Terminal – [Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano).

**Step 3:** Now you can make a simple change to the file. Paste these lines of code to change your Terminal prompt.

```
export PS1="___________________    | \w @ \h (\u) \n| => "

export PS2="| => "
```

**Step 4:** Now save your changes by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to save. Then exit Nano by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

**Step 5:** Now we need to *activate your changes. Type source .bash_profile and watch your prompt change.

That's it! Enjoy!