# OSX Terminal how to add downloads folder to path

Tags: macos, download, terminal, path

How can you add the Downloads folder to the terminal path; or if you can't, where should you move your files so that they can be read by terminal? I am using j2objc and need to be able to use the j2objc command, and now it says command not found when I try to do it. I tried moving the j2objc folder to usr/local/bin but it doesn't work still.

Comment: You can, but that sounds like a bad idea. You can place single binaries in `/usr/local/bin` (or symlink them there from another directory) or add another dedicated directory to your path. You might also want to checkout a packages manager like Homebrew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit $PATH (.bash\_profile) on OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx)