# How to make MySQL dump file from terminal on Mac?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

How to import and export MySQL dump file on a Mac?

Like on Windows, I use this code:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases DBname>d:\ FILENAME.sql
```

But it does not work on Mac terminal. It produces the following error:

```
-bash: mysqldump: command not found
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: -bash: mysqldump: command not found

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The location where `mysqldump` is installed need to be declared in your `$PATH`.

If you don't know how to edit your `$PATH` on macOS, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx).

For example, if your `mysqldump` binary is located in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`, you can edit your `$PATH` to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

With this modification, you won't have to provide the full path to the `mysqldump` binary every time and will be able to use your command:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --databases DBname>d:\ FILENAME.sql
```

Comment: If you're using MAMP, then the mysqldump location is /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos  thank you.

Answer (score 7):

i forget to give path to it the query is

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p friendstree > friendstree.sql

it worked