# I'm getting php5.5 instead php7 when I run exec(php -v) in php script

Tags: php, macports

When I run php -v in cli I get the exact php version 7, but when i run exec("php -v") in web server I get php 5.5 even thought in phpinfo i see that I am runing php 7?! Any idea why I get the older version of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

running `exec` you get the CLI version of PHP
you probably installed php5.5 as CLI and php7 as apache module

Comment: when I check on terminal about my php -v I can see that my version of php is PHP7

Comment: run `which php` in both you script and command line. Also the php configured for your apache user (ie : www-data) may differ from the php cli for user

Comment: it shows me the path where my php is located /local/bin/php

Comment: Both which show the exact same path to php ? I think it's not possible : if you have 2 concurrent versions of php they've got to be on different locations

Comment: when i run whereis php it shows both the same location. I dont know for what reason which php i do not get the result in php script

Answer (score 1):

If you use CentOs, add this line at the end of `/etc/bashrc` (or `~/.profile` for Ubuntu)

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/your/path/to/php7/bin
```

Then run:
`source /etc/bashrc`

P/s It may be better if you edit  `/etc/profile.d`. Take a look both of them.

**UPDATE**

In MacOS, let edit `~/.bash_profile` (create it if it does not exist) with the same content.

Comment: Why is this used for? when I run php -v in command line I get php 7 version it's just when I run exec("php -v") on controller of symfony project I get the wrong version of php (php 5.5).

Comment: It's Environment Path. You have to declare PATH for OS know where to find and run the executed files. When you run `php -v`, the cli version will run, not the php web server process. So, let point OS out to php bin dir

Comment: I am using CentOS. And sorry but Im new in using CentOS where can I find the path to execute this commands?

Comment: Try `which php`, `whereis php` or create `info.php`, which contain "<?php phpinfo (); ?>". Put it in your web root, access localhost/info.php and look up the path in there. Maybe you will find in configure params or further...

Comment: I am able to find the path of the php exe file but not the ~/.bashrc is it possible that it does not have and i have to create it?

Comment: Sorry, I have a confusion between CentOs and Ubuntu. With centos, it places at /etc/bashrc

Comment: I used macports to install apache2 and php, and I do not find any file as bashrc

Comment: If you use CentOS, it certain places at /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile.d. It is not related to apache, php or macport

Comment: I am using OS X El Capitan and I dont have under /etc/ folder bashrc or profile.d ?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128658/discussion-between-sasser-and-davuz).

Comment: hi  @Sasser , sorry for late, if you use Mac OX, plz either create or edit `~/.bash_profile` . See more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx

Comment: hi @Davuz, sorry for late respond, I resolve the  problem by updating the path in php-fpm. I needed there to to update the path.