# Setting ANDROID_HOME environment variable Mac,Cordova

Tags: android, macos, cordova

Failing requirements check tried setting environment variable newbie here

```
    Karthiks-Mini:sgame karthikn$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/karthikn/Library/Android/sdk
    Karthiks-Mini:sgame karthikn$ export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
    Karthiks-Mini:sgame karthikn$ source ~/.bash_profile
   -bash: /Users/karthikn/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
   Karthiks-Mini:sgame karthikn$ cordova requirements

   Requirements check results for android:
   Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
   Android SDK: installed true
   Android target: not installed 
   Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is        not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
   Gradle: not installed 
   Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
   Looked here: /Users/karthikn/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
   Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting ANDROID\_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)