# Flutter command not found

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, command-line, terminal

Apparently, none of the Flutter commands are working in the terminal of Android Studio which I believe I am trying to run it at the root of my project.

Output:

```
bash: flutter: command not found
```

Answer (score 605, accepted):

You need to correctly set up your Flutter path.

From *[macOS install - Update your path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)*:

1. Determine the directory where you placed the Flutter SDK. You will need this in Step 3.
2. Open (or create) `$HOME/.bash_profile`. You can do that by using terminal text editor by going in terminal and typing `nano ~/.bash_profile`

   [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) uses the Z shell by default, so edit $file *HOME/.zshrc*.

   If you are using a different shell, the file path and filename will be different on your machine.
3. Add the following line and change `[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]` to be the path where you cloned Flutter’s Git repository is:

   ```
    export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
   ```

   For example:

   ```
    export PATH=~/Documents/flutter/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and when it asks you to save the file, choose <kbd>Yes</kbd>
5. Run `source $HOME/.bash_profile` to refresh the current window or restart the terminal
6. Verify that the `flutter/bin` directory is now in your PATH by running:

   ```
    echo $PATH
   ```

   Notice that `[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]` is where you installed Flutter SDK, not the location of your app

Instead of [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano), you can use any text editor to edit file `~/.bash_profile`.

For **zsh**:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run: `nano ~/.zshrc`
3. Add: `export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH`
4. Run: `source ~/.zshrc`
5. restart terminal
6. Run: `flutter doctor -v`

For example : if flutter in your machine has been installed under [your_username]/Developer/flutter

```
export PATH=Developer/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Hi @Tree: After did above steps. And then run `echo $PATH` get the result: `/Users/username/Documents/Project/Test/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:Users/username/Documents/Flutter/flutter/bin`. But I still got the same error when run `flutter create -t module myapp_flutter`

Comment: Error: `-bash: flutter: command not found`. Please help me fix it.

Comment: Doesn't work when the terminal is reopened, please help.

Comment: @FutureJJ Restart Your Computer

Comment: @m3g4tr0n nope doesn't fix the issue. Exporting the above-mentioned path in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile fixed my issue.

Comment: Great ..I am using Linux Mint 19.1 and adding code provided above in /etc/profile + restarting solved my issue..Without restarting the solution provided above doesn't work when terminal is reopened

Comment: @Tree, step 5, very important. I have seen videos that omit it. Thank you.

Comment: @FutureJJ Updating in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile worked for me too

Comment: @m3g4tr0n: Even after restarting my PC didn't work! I'm using MAC OS.

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle Check out Caner's answer below it's for MAC OS

Comment: Why is modifying .bash_profile works instead of .bashrc or vice-versa on a Mac? The installation guide on flutter.io says it's .bashrc we need to add the line but it was not the case for me.

Comment: Adding path in my *.profile* worked for me , add this in terminal *gedit ~/.profile*, and  then add export PATH=/home/myUser/development/flutter/bin:$PATH

Comment: Step 3 is confused where to add this (Add the following line and change)?

Comment: pdating in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile worked for me

Comment: I cannot find the "Flutter SDK" I do however see "fluttter_patched_sdk" twice and "flutter_patched_sdk_product" twice. Where would it normally be stored?

Comment: Great instruction, worked on macOS 10.15 (Catalina). Good to follow because of the detailed and concrete examples!!

Comment: `echo $SHELL` will tell which shell you are using.

Comment: If you're struggling using ~/.zshrc be sure to remove the quotes!

Comment: Write export PATH="$PATH:/home/mangesh/Documents/flutter_data/flutter/bin/"
in bash profile it works for me also mentioned on flutter doc. May be different for different shell.

Comment: for me I added in .bash_profile { export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/"
export PATH="/Users/CHANGETHISTOYOURS/flutter/bin:$PATH" } and it worked in terminal and android studio with no issues !

Comment: source ~/.zshrc ,what i was missing

Comment: How do I "Determine the directory where [I] placed the Flutter SDK"? Android Studio downloaded the plugin from the plugin market place, and it doesn't want to tell me where it put it!... 

Comment: I downloaded flutter sdk zip and extracted in my user folder. I tried many ways on MacOS ventura for setting Flutter path through zshrc, zprofile, none worked, for reasons i am not sure. Then  I git cloned flutter sdk and added path in .zshrc and magically it worked.

Answer (score 457):

I tried out all the methods in previous answers, but all of them lasted only while the terminal was open. So I went ahead and directly added it to the path file permanently.

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

Add this to the file (Your Flutter Bin Path):

```
/Users/yourUserName/Development/flutter/bin
```

Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Close the terminal and reopen it again. Tada!

Comment: This worked. Just to expand the response. After adding the path to the file, press CTRL + X, Y and then ENTER. Now completely close(Quit) the terminal and reopen it again. Try the command flutter and it should work

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thank you!

To clarify for other beginners, you need to add "Users/yourUserName/yourPathToWhereYouInstalledFlutter/flutter/bin" 

(In my case, "/Development/" was "/Developer/SDKs/")

Comment: I can't understand how to config this

Comment: For people like me who dont use macs - this above method works. Just open Visual studio, type the "sudo nano /etc/paths" line, which opens up a file in the terminal, then you literally add the next line to the bottom of the list and save it. close and reopen terminal and it works. My flutter sdk was installed on desktop so replaced "/Development" with "/Desktop"

Comment: This is the way the tutorial should have people do it, thanks! Don't forget to open a new terminal and test it flutter works globally by checking the version outside of the flutter folder using "flutter --version"

Comment: only this answer is helpful for me

Answer (score 91):

If you are using **[zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/)**, you need to follow the steps below on Mac.

- Download the latest Flutter version from [the official site](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos).
- Unzip it and move to the `$HOME` location of your Mac.
- Add to the path via the `.zshrc` file.
- Run `nano  ~/.zshrc` into an [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2) terminal.
- Export `PATH=$HOME/flutter/bin:$PATH`
- Save and close the `~/.zshrc` file.
- Restart iTerm2.
- Now you will have the Flutter executable available.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 The solution worked while using ZSH terminal the .bashrc and .bash_profile do not work only the .zshrc solves the problem

Comment: Thanks. If you are BigSur user, try only this.

Answer (score 70):

Do the following steps:

1. Download the Flutter SDK

   [Flutter SDK Archive](https://flutter.io/sdk-archive/#linux)
2. Extract it where do you want (for example `/home/development/flutter`)
3. Set your PATH. Edit your file with the command `gedit ~/.profile`. You need to add this line:

   ```
   export PATH=[location_where_you_extracted_flutter]/flutter/bin:$PATH
   ```

   I showed you above where I've extracted mine, so my export will look like this:

   ```
   export PATH=/home/myUser/development/flutter/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Save the file and close it.
5. Run `source ~/.profile` to load the changes
6. If you now run `flutter doctor`, it should work!

Comment: Still are perfect answer to Manjaro problems and Arch base.

Comment: thanks bro this worked for me, however for catelina I have used .zshrc instead .profile

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in macOS Catalina, 
however following below according to the Flutter docs wasn't working for me:
`export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
`

Comment: I tried and all in vain but then I added double quotes  export PATH="/home/hamza/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin:$PATH"  and it worked for me .

Answer (score 37):

**If you are on macOS**

First find the location of your Flutter SDK

Flutter SDK File: Write the below command on your terminal to download the Flutter SDK

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

For example: the SDK executable file name is `flutter` and it is in folder *Downloads*

Close and open your terminal again.

And enter the following commands in your terminal

```
cd Downloads # Go to Downloads

cd flutter   # Go to folder 'flutter'

pwd          # /Users/[USERNAME]/downloads/flutter/

whoami       # Your [USERNAME]

export PATH="/Users/[USERNAME]/downloads/flutter/bin":$PATH
```

Answer (score 31):

For zsh users:

1. Open terminal run

   touch $HOME/.zshrc
2. Run

   sudo nano ~/.zshrc
3. Type

   export PATH=$PATH:/Path to your extracted flutter/Flutter/bin
4. Press ctrl+x then press y
5. Press Enter
6. Close the terminal and open a new terminal and run

   flutter doctor

Comment: Nice! Worked for me!

Comment: thanks that's work for me too on macOS Monterey (12.1)

Comment: For me, export PATH="$HOME/{path}/flutter/bin:$PATH" worked

Comment: superb straight forward, work for me

Answer (score 24):

#### [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave); Wireshark Path problem

In your terminal, run:

```
touch $HOME/.bash_profile

vi $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Now use `I` to insert and paste the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME:/PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY/flutter/bin"
```

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> and type `:wq!` to save the file and exit.

Refresh:

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

And verify it's OK by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: What is the *"[Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) Path problem"*?

Comment: Did the same it doesn't work, please check your solution

Answer (score 16):

Do this to add the Flutter executable permanently to your path (in Ubuntu):

1. `cd $HOME`
2. `gedit .bashrc`
3. Append the line:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:[location_where_you_extracted_flutter]/flutter/bin"
   ```

   in the text file and save it.
4. `source $HOME/.bashrc`
5. Open new terminal and run the `flutter doctor` command

Comment: Please use the markdown feature of the text editor to structure your answer a little more, so that it's easier for others to read and understand.

Answer (score 15):

You must have the *.bash_profile* file and define the *flutter path* in the *.bash_profile* file.

1. First of all, if you do not have or do not know file *.bash_profile*, please look my answer:
   [How do I edit $PATH (.bash_profile) on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx/54937608#54937608)
2. You should add the below line (.../flutter_SDK_path/flutter/bin) in your **.bash_profile**:

   ```
    export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/Documents/flutter_SDK_path/flutter/bin
   ```

After these steps, you can write Flutter code such as, `flutter doctor`, `flutter build ios`, `flutter clean`, etc. in the terminal of a MacBook.

Comment: This absolutely works! (if it does not, restart your terminal)

Comment: This worked for me too! And it still works after restart of terminal

Answer (score 13):

Previously I was giving my whole path like this:

```
export PATH=Users/Tekion/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

It started working after I changed my whole path to

```
export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 12):

On [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina), the issue is with the Path environment variable.

1. Open Terminal and check the shell (command: `echo $SHELL`),

If output is `/bin/bash`, we need to convert to [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`Zsh`). Z shell is only the default shell on newly created user accounts, so any existing accounts you have on an upgraded Mac will still use Bash by default unless you change it. Simply run the `chsh -s` (change shell) command in a Terminal window.

(command: `chsh -s /bin/zsh`)

Enter your password when prompted. After you close the terminal window and reopen it, you’ll be using Z shell.

2. Update your Path

2.1. Open the zshrc file (command: `vim ~/.zshrc`)

2.2. Press 'I' to insert the path as (`export PATH=~/Dev/flutter/bin:$PATH`). Here `~/Dev/` is the folder where Flutter is installed

2.3. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and then `:wq` to save and exit the file

3. Done! try (command: `flutter doctor`)

Answer (score 8):

Add Path in this way in `.bashrc` of android sdk and tools with   flutter

```
export PATH=$PATH:/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.1:/user/Android/Sdk/tools:/user/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/user/Documents/fluterdev/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Then run this command

> `source ~/.profile`

Then run this command:

**On Linux**

```
source ~/.profile
```

**On Mac**

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or:

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile
```

[image]

Then you can user any of flutter command like to build fluter apk

> `flutter build apk`

Comment: This worked, none of the other methods worked, the magic was to export the path to bashrc instead of any other paths. Thanks!!

Comment: @RonyB. i could not find "text file window. " in my code please describe

Comment: please add more detail. where is .bashrc file?

Answer (score 6):

The Flutter SDK can be run on Windows as well as macOS.

***For Windows***

1. First download the latest SDK from the [Flutter download page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows).
2. Now to run `flutter` in the Windows console, you need to update your PATH environment variable.
3. From the Start search bar, type ‘env’ and select *Edit environment variables* for your account.
4. Under *User variables*, check if there is an entry called *Path*:

   1. If the entry does exist, append the full path to `flutter\bin` using `;` as a separator from the existing values.
   2. If the entry does not exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full path to `flutter\bin` as its value.

***For Mac***

1. First download the latest SDK from the [Flutter download page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)
2. Extract the file in the desired location using following commands:

   1. `cd ~/development`
   2. unzip `~/Downloads/flutter_macos_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable.zip`
3. Add the Flutter tool to your path:

   1. `export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"`

**Run `flutter doctor`**

Answer (score 6):

The Flutter installation issue in macOS (specific for [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur)).

1. Check which shell is your default shell that you have in the terminal.
2. To check the default shell, type command `echo $SHELL`.
3. For my specific issue I have [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (zsh) as my default shell.
4. So I change my Z shell as my default shell to Bash.
5. To change the default shell, enter the below command.
   chsh -s /bin/bash
6. Enter your password when you are prompted
7. Now I have the Bash shell as my default.
8. Then I just follow the standard process for the Flutter setup on Flutter’s official site.
9. And I have successfully configured Flutter in my macOS.

Extract the file in the desired location, for example:

```
cd ~/development
unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_1.22.5-stable.zip
```

Add the flutter tool to your path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

This command sets your PATH variable for the current terminal window only. To permanently add Flutter to your path, see below.

—> Determine the directory where you placed the Flutter SDK.
—>     Open (or create) the rc file for your shell. Typing echo $SHELL in your Terminal tells you which shell you’re using. If you’re using Bash, edit $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc. If you’re using Z shell, edit *$HOME/.zshrc*. If you’re using a different shell, the file path and filename will be different on your machine.

—> Add the following line and change [PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY] to be the path where you cloned Flutter’s Git repository

```
export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
```

—>     Run source `$HOME/.<rc file>` to refresh the current window, or open a new terminal window to automatically source the file.

—> Verify that the `flutter/bin` directory is now in your PATH by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

—> Verify that the `flutter` command is available by running

—> `which flutter`

—> Now run below command.

```
 $ which flutter dart
       /path-to-flutter-sdk/bin/flutter
      /usr/local/bin/dart
```

—> And you're good to go.

Comment: My issues was this error 

`bash: melos: command not found`

and ultimately this worked for me 


`flutter pub global activate melos 0.4.11+2`

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 14.*:

There isn't any `.bash_profile` file, but it just the `.profile` file in folder `/home/mangesh`.

In my case, I am running this command to add the `flutter/bin` path,

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/mangesh/Documents/flutter_data/flutter/bin/"
```

To verify the above change, just run,

```
echo $PATH
```

Following is my complete output,

```
$ pwd

/home/mangesh

$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/mangesh/Documents/flutter_data/flutter/bin/"

$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/mangesh/Documents/flutter_data/flutter/bin/
```

Comment: You ought to add note about `mangesh` being *your* user name (thus different for everybody else) - or similar. But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the checked answer, but when I restart the terminal, the Flutter command is not recognized again. My in file *bash_profile* path is:

`export PATH=~/Users/aldo/Projects/Framework/flutter/bin:$PATH` with `~`

Then I edit it to:

`export PATH=/Users/aldo/Projects/Framework/flutter/bin:$PATH` without `~`

And re run `source $HOME/.bash_profile`: Now my Flutter command is recognized even if I restart the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create a symbolic link as below,

```
sudo ln -s /opt/flutter/bin/flutter /usr/bin/flutter
```

I had moved the executable `flutter` into the `/opt/` folder after downloading, so replace it with the path you have for the directory the `flutter` executable is in.

The `flutter` command should work even after rebooting your machine.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I put the line `export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH` in both file *.bash_profile* and *.bashrc* (I put it on the last line).

After that, run `source .bash_profile` and `source .bashrc`. Now it's working (even if you use it in a new terminal window)!

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, there are two options to solve this issue.

**Option 1: Adding the Flutter SDK path permanently (it will work in any terminal session)**

Download the Flutter SDK and extract in any location and then you have to add the below line in *$HOME/.bash_profile* file (hidden folder as default).

```
export PATH="$PATH:[where the Flutter SDK is downloaded and extracted]/flutter/bin"
```

For example:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/development/tools/flutter/bin"
```

**Option 2: If you are facing any difficulties with Option 1, then this is much simpler, but you have to do this simple step whenever you restart your system/terminal.**

Step 1: Go to the path where Flutter SDK downloaded and extracted (for example: `cd ~/Development/tools/`)

Step 2: Enter this command

```
export PATH='pwd'/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

That's it. Type "flutter doctor" to check if this issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Just revert to `chsh -s /bin/bash` from `chsh -s /bin/zsh`,

Run one command

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

You're facing this problem just because you have changed the shell from [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) to [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) in macOS. If you run this command again it will change the path again.
So just run one command and the problem is solved.

Comment: Wasn't it an macOS upgrade that changed the default shell?

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac I followed the [steps of the user Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-command-not-found/50653621#50653621), but I still received the answer "flutter: command not found".

I then went to the folder `flutter/bin` and inside this folder <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click on the `flutter` executable and in the popup I clicked open. After that the Mac already recognized this as an exception and the Flutter commands already work.

Answer (score 2):

[Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus):

I added the path correctly for Flutter, Java, Android Studio, and Android SDK in the *.bashrc file*, but when I run `flutter doctor`, the terminal returns:

```
flutter: command not found
```

Solution:

So, first I had to always run:

```
sudo su
```

And then:

```
source /home/your_name/.bashrc
```

Then run `flutter doctor`. It works fine.

So every time, *if* I want to run `flutter doctor`, I have to run these two commands above.

Answer (score 2):

The Flutter installation guide says you add this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:pwd/flutter/bin"
```

Visual Studio Code doesn't support `pwd` for some reason. The fix:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: Perhaps the guide doesn't mean "pwd" ***literally***, but "current working directory"? Or the environment variable `PWD` (capital letters - the notation would probably need to be `$PWD` or `${PWD}`)? In any case, how reliable is the current working directory (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 2):

For those using a Z shell resource (.zshrc), navigate to your home directory and open .zprofile, copy and paste this: `export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH`

Comment: you can use backticks (\`) to set off monospaced code text.  Example: `export PATH=$PATH` (this is typed as \`export PATH=$PATH\`)

https://commonmark.org/help/

Comment: "resource" for "rc"? Doesn't it stand for ["run commands"](https://www.wikitechy.com/technology/rc-bashrc-stand/)? (Though, I was once told it stood for "recovery".)

Answer (score 2):

First, download the Flutter here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

When you created the folder with Flutter SDK, open it in Terminal using the following command:

```
cd ~/development
```

If there is no development folder run this command first:

```
mkdir /development
```

After that, you need to run the unzip command. Make sure you specify the correct path to the downloaded Flutter archive file.
Run the command below:

```
unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_1.17.1-stable.zip
```

Setting the Flutter tool path

In order to set up the Flutter tool path you should run this command:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

Next, you need to know which shell you are using. For this run this command:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Depending on the shell run the following command: [Note, the command you will be using depends on the shell you have.]

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
sudo nano /.bashrc
```

After that in the new window, you need to add a path to the flutter tool.

Use the following command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/development/flutter/bin
```

The next thing you need to do is to check the Flutter dependencies.

For this, run the command:

```
flutter doctor
```

This operation will help you to identify if there are any dependencies you need to install.
After the results will be prepared click Agree and wait for the installation of the needed dependencies to complete the setup.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq7OK.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this issue from a Windows 10 machine, this is how I solved it:

First of all, find your Flutter executable path, and then your bin folder under the Flutter path

E.g., "C:\flutter\bin"

Copy it, and press the windows button. Type: environment, and press "Edit the system environment variable"

Press the "Environment variable" button

Double click on the "Path" menu

Add a new path, using the bin address

E.g., ""C:\flutter\bin"

This should work.