# "flutter: command not found" in ubuntu

Tags: installation, flutter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm having trouble with installing Flutter on ubuntu.

Attached is an image of my terminal with the steps I've followed, and the files associated with the flutter directory.

I've followed the steps shown on https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/linux and also tried to install with git clone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltmNd.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter commands not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-commands-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `pwd` part of the `export` command.

**Replace** the single quotes in `'pwd'` with Backtick/back quote (``) like this

`` export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin" ``

---

***EDITED***

Above command will just work until you close the terminal.
To make the change ***permanent*** you have to edit the `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`, etc), using a text editor like vim, gedit or nano and place the same command at the end of the file.

`vim ~/.bashrc` or `nano ~/.bashrc`

Add the next line at the end of the file

```sh
# Add flutter to the path
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

***Restart your terminal*** and verify that your PATH was set correctly with the `echo $PATH` command

Good luck!!

Comment: It will not run after close and open terminal, and unable to run at another terminal like VS Code.

Comment: @151291 Thanks for letting me know. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux 18.04 version.
first, add the flutter path in .bash_profile as

```
export PATH="$PATH:(''flutter path)/flutter/bin"
```

I have this problem.run the following command in the terminal

```
source '(flutter path)'.bash_profile'
```