# My android studio doesn't see my virtual and physical devices

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device

My android studio is doesn't see my devices virtual/physical. (I am using ubuntu)

I've already tried change the platform-tools in home/user/android/sdk, delete and download the avd and my physical phones developer settings and debugging settings is on.

This is the screenshot of the problem.

[image: snap]

By the way there is no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these commands;

```
adb kill-server // kill server
adb start-server // start server
adb devices // show all active devices
```

If this problem will not be resolved, please restart Android Studio

Comment: Thanks for help. It works, android studio saw the devices. But when I run it's running with a error: " Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components. " (i am developing with flutter) and then when I write "flutter doctor" in terminal it's running with "flutter: command not found" even flutter plugins are downloaded

Comment: You need to update path. You can more information from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653621/6136201