# Uploading build to App store Error: "ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage"?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using Xcode version 11.1. My app is a Flutter app.

I am trying to upload my mobile app using Xcode and App Store connect. I have all the necessary info on app store connect except for the actual build. I cannot get the build to upload based on the following error (according to Apple):

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "******" 1.0.0 (0.1). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _ptrace. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:
>
> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I understand the second error is not necessary, but I wanted to include all the email text, just in case I'm missing something. I've been reading online a lot of people are having issues with the last few Xcode updates?

How can I upload my app?*

Comment: Same problem here. Have found any solution?

Comment: Same here, I guess Flutter team should resolve something!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upload my app successfully!
Here’s what I changed: 
As Thoai mentioned, I tried to run the flutter iOS build command from my terminal, but I kept getting the error I mentioned (command not found) so all I had to do for that was to update my path, and then I was able to run the command, and it worked.

How to update your flutter path: 
[Flutter command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-command-not-found/50653621#50653621)

Answer (score 1):

For escaping _ptrace symbol in your Flutter app, use code below for build application:

```
   flutter clean
   rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
   flutter build ios --release
```

After you can upload your archive to App Store Connect.
Additional info about fix that you can found link below:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37850

Answer (score 0):

You try root directory project and excute com "flutter build ios" in terminal

Comment: I keep getting "-bash: flutter: command not found" error with that method, that's why I've been using Xcode

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, then edit the "Run" scheme -- change the "Build Configuration" to "Release".

[image]

Comment: Its just Run configuration, this solution is useless. 
Archive configuration needed for App Store set as Release by default.