# Issue in building apk in flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

i have completed all the steps like creating keyStore , changing in build.gradle etc. 
but i am facing a **issue** while running this command

```
flutter build apk --release
```

whenever i run this command terminal shows that

I am using Linux

**flutter: command not found**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Give us a little more context, like , are you on Windows or mac or Linux?

Comment: i am using Linux

Comment: You may be able to resolve your issue if you follow this stackoverflow thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653621/7938870

Comment: i tried a lot but path is changing temporarily whenever i opens the terminal again it shows the previous path .

Comment: Thanks i have solved this issue by changing the path in android terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added installdirectory/flutter/bin to your path variables?

Comment: See the flutter installation guide

Comment: "Update you path" section

Answer (score 0):

you should locate flutter in path [click here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path)