# not able to run flutter on the command line

Tags: flutter

I have am trying to run the flutter command on the terminal but it keeps printing out the same error message about it being not a clone of the github project. I have tried everything. I updated the path in the .bash_profile like the instructions said in the flutter docs and I also even tried the `sudo nano /etc/paths` method and it still doesn't work. I am out of ideas and would appreciate your help.

```
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to set up Flutter, run the following command:
       git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

I even ran that command in this error message as well and still no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-command-not-found)

Comment: nope :( it didnt thnx for trying tho

Comment: Make sure you read *all* of the answers.

Comment: I've already read all of them. Nothing works :( My only speculation now is that I'm not using this```git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git``` in the correct directory, if that even matters, that is.