# Process 'command '/Users/username/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to open a flutter project and have just installed flutter. When I run `flutter doctor -v` in the terminal I installed it, I get the following:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.401, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103
    x86_64, locale en-UA)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-10.0.pre.401 at /Users/username/flutter
```

However in another terminal window if I run `flutter doctor -v` I get `flutter command not found`

I downloaded flutter directly into my users account so my bash_profile looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

I also added this to my local.properties which is when I get the error when I try to run the app:

```
flutter.sdk=/Users/username/flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that Flutter path has just not been set properly. That's why the changes on bash_profile doesn't persist. Running `export PATH...` only applies on the current terminal window. You'd need to run `source $HOME/.bash_profile` to refresh the config. See this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653621/2497859) for the complete steps.