# Error "The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm trying to install flutterfire_cli in my root project, so I typed this command:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

After that, this is the console session (PowerShell):

```
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\eventually
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

Output:

```
Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.1.1+2.
Resolving dependencies...
The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `global deactivate flutterfire_cli`.
Installed executable flutterfire.
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated flutterfire_cli 0.1.1+2.
```

To fix the warning, I added **C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin** to my [Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable in the system variables environment. (But it does not work, I'm still getting the warning)

Next, I'm trying to generate the *firebase_options.dart* file as [the documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) says using this command:

```
flutterfire configure
```

But I'm getting an error in the console (PowerShell):

```
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\eventually
flutterfire configure
```

Output:

```
flutterfire : The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutterfire configure
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutterfire:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I missing? Why am I getting this error even if the Firebase CLI is already installed on my machine?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Go through this doc very carefully: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/

Step 1: Install [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

Step 2: Install FlutterFire CLI with this command `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

While doing this you must notice the following warning

`Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path. You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable. A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.`

This means you need to add `C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` into your System's environment path. It would be better if you restart the computer after **adding it to the path variable.**

For MacOS run: `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`

Step 3: Now `flutterfire configure` should work.

If still not working play with [Firebase commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

Comment: For MacOS do: export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Comment: Do not forget to restart your machine after setting the environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot, I was facing the same issue

Comment: If anyone from the Dart team ever sees this: please, pretty please, make this warning more visible. It's so easy to miss right now, amid all the output! Why not make "Warning" fully uppercase and change its colour to e.g. orange?

Answer (score 69):

For Mac -> Execute this command:

`export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`

Answer (score 33):

Three 3 steps for getting it work on Windows:

1. Run this command:

   dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
2. Type env into Windows search and open Edit the system environment variables --> Environment variables --> System variables( the one on the bottom of the window) --> Double click on Path --> New and enter this:

   C:\Users\PutHereYourUsername\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
3. `flutterfire configure` command should work now - close and open again command prompt or other terminal. Sometimes there is a problem with other editors and terminals where `flutterfire configure` still does not work. In that case open Command Prompt and it works there for sure.

Comment: I also had to restart VSCode for it to work. Closing and reopening the integrated termincal wasn't enough.

Answer (score 21):

As for me, I have done everything correctly and the command works if I run in the Windows command prompt, but it fails to work if I type the command inside the VS code terminal.

So I just killed the terminal and opened it again, then it works.

Or, you can try restarting your machine.

Comment: You're right; killing the terminal and opening a new one fixed it, after I also added "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin" to path. Also, the installation of the official Firebase CLI is required, it can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli

Comment: It appears that installing the Firebase CLI binary file does not work, you have to use the npm command which requires node installed. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410843/firebasecommandexception-an-error-occured-on-the-firebase-cli-when-attempting-t

Comment: I had to restart vsCode for it to work, kinda weird but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 15):

Even after adding C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin to the path for me flutterfire would not work from the command line, the reason being that it actually instally a flutterfire.bat file.

So I use flutterfire.bat in the command line as of now and that is working.

Answer (score 12):

For Linux/Ubuntu run this command in the terminal,

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Which you will also notice in the terminal when you run the command ↓.

> dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure you are your **project directory**
2. run this `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Windows:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70325312/11731185

**Mac:**

1. Open Terminal and run:

   ```
   dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
   export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
   ```
2. Run: `flutterfire --version`
3. If you get a version number, `flutterfire` has been installed successfully

Answer (score 2):

For Linux/Ubuntu you should do the following:

1. Open your .bashrc file using the command "sudo nano ~/.bashrc"
2. Add export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin" to the end of the file.
3. Final you can source the file using "source ~/.bashrc"
4. It should now be able to recognize the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ flutterfire.bat configure
```

try this if you are windows user.....

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

for macOS Monterey edit ~/.zprofile instead .zshrc

Answer (score 1):

This was the hack i used to solve mine. I copied and pasted the `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` in my folder search bar to enter the folder, note I could not find any folder called AppData, but when I pasted it on the folder search it did take me to the `bin` folder.

In the bin folder, you will find a file called `flutterfire.bat`. Copy and paste the flutterfire.bat file in the root of your project and then run the `.\flutterfire configure` command. Please do note the `dot (.)` and `forward-slash (\)`. You need to add it to work.

Comment: The reason why you couldnt findthe "Appdata" folder was because its hidden by default in windows. toggle show hidden files and folders option and you can see them

Answer (score 1):

for mac m1 , add
`export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` at the top of users/username/.profile , works on (monterey)

Answer (score 1):

For me, even after I installed everything correctly, restarting my IDE(VSCode) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu add followong to your bashrc file

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Steps:

1. nano ~/.bashrc
2. paste `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` to bottom of file
3. ctrl^O then enter then ctrl^X
4. Restart your IDE

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-command-not-found)
Here is very easy instructions for adding something to your path on Mac, It solved my issues with Flutter and Flutterfire.

Answer (score 0):

The export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin" did not work on my Debian machine!

I removed the first line `#!/usr/bin/env sh` from $HOME/.pub-cache/bin/flutterfire file and the flutterfire command worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

it will not work in GitBash or vsCode terminal , you have to open windows cmd and run it .(after settng up path as already mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in windows for several hours and I want to share my solution. I downloaded the [standalone binary](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows) and put it in the parent of my root folder. I then duplicated the .exe and renamed it to firebase.exe and moved it into my flutter project folder. In VSCode I activated the firebase-tools-instant-win.exe to use as my shell (firebase login etc...) In the shell you cd flutter_project\ and then you can run your `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli` and `flutterfire configure`.

Final Structure Outline

- Repository

  - flutter_project

    - flutter files
    - firebase.exe (duplicated exe)
  - flutter_project_2
  - flutter_project_3
  - firebase-tools-instant-win.exe (use this shell)

I also have added `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` to system env variable: PATH
Hope this helps someone... This was a very frustrating problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

After executing the 'flutterfire configure' command in Firebase CLI. Got the below error as

```
⠏ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Error: C:\Users\VSS00\CACHE~1\firebase\runtime\node....

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:300:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:390:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main
```

**Solution**

- Ensure you have logged into the Firebase CLI with the valid account and created a project in the Firebase console
- Close the Android Studio (or) VS Code
- open the file 'node.bat' from C:\Users\PC.cache\firebase\runtime (it will open an another Firebase CLI terminal)
- navigate to the Flutter project directory in the terminal (like E:/projects/myflutterapp)
- Run the command : flutterfire configure

It will list out the project and you can move forward.

Answer (score 0):

sudo flutterfire configure this work for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't work because I initially attempted to call it from outside the project directory. When I copied the absolute path to my project and navigated to it with '`cd path`', it finally worked.

Answer (score -4):

Use command prompt.. not the vsc terminal

Answer (score -4):

if you followed the right answer and still not working, you need to restart your computer