# How to run Flutter commands on Android Studio Terminal

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I can run the flutter project from the macOS terminal and Android Studio, but I can't run from Android Studio terminal.

Macbook Air M1

macOS Monterey 12.2

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1

[caps1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weOpv.png)

[caps2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeWoe.jpg)

[caps3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YAHT.png)

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-command-not-found

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did everything. MacOS terminal works fine. I just have a problem with Android Studio terminal.

Answer (score 0):

if Android Studio doesen't find the command flutter then Android Studio doesen't find the flutter sdk.

so please look if the path of the flutter sdk is correctly wittend.