# Creation error in flutter, how can I work fix this?

Tags: flutter

When I open new project, It happens error like below.
I installed flutter new version and put sdk path in right. but I don't get why can't build and error like this.
I'll appreciate for your advice.

[image]

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor` and share the log

Comment: /Users/shinheejin/Documents/Rocat/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
/Users/shinheejin/Documents/Rocat/flutter/bin/flutter: line 41: dirname: command not found
/Users/shinheejin/Documents/Rocat/flutter/bin/flutter: line 41: cd: : No such file or directory
/Users/shinheejin/Documents/Rocat/flutter/bin/flutter: line 42: basename: command not found
/Users/shinheejin/Documents/Rocat/flutter/bin/flutter: line 54: uname: command not found
Process finished with exit code 127

Comment: T.T help plz...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50652071/10157127 may solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Run flutter doctor if not fix check flutter update and run flutter upgrade.