# Flutter iOS build failed: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, macos

`flutter build ipa` is failing on [macOS v13.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) with Xcode 14.3 and Flutter 3.7.9.

Log output:

```
xcodebuild[83777:409216] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
```

`flutter run` works without issues on iOS simulators.

Comment: I have the same error. My problem started with Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3) and when I apply the fix, run without issues on simulators but when I try to build ipa this error happens.

Comment: Flutter now has the issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Xcode for version 14.2, You can use the Xcode Select for this.

Comment: This is not a solution, one day you'll have to update to 14.3 and deal with this.

Answer (score 49):

Currently this is the only one solution working for me to build Archive ipa. Without need to roll back to Xcode 14.2.

So the solution for now is, open ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh file.

Find this line:

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
fi
```

to

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
fi
```

add -f and save the file.

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: It works for me. 

FYI : In case your file keep revert back. Don't open file with Android studio or Xcode. Use TextEdit to edit and save file.

Comment: It's fixed in Cocoapods version 1.12.1 (release April 19th 2023) so if you use that version, no need to replace any code in the script. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.12.1

Answer (score 25):

You don't need to rollback to Xcode 14.2. The following steps worked for me in 14.3 version:

1. Make sure you are handling version 11 as Target:

   In the podfile file...

   Replace

   ```
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
   ```

   With

   ```
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
      end
    end
   ```
2. Make sure that debug is included within the LaunchAction Xcode schema. In the *Runner.xcscheme* file you need to be sure that something like that is included...

   ```
    <LaunchAction
       buildConfiguration = "Debug"
       //...more lines
    </LaunchAction>
   ```

Comment: The `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` on its own didn't work, but the LaunchAction set to Debug resolved things for me.

Comment: This saved me. Only needed to change the `buildConfiguration` to `debug`.

Comment: @NickolasdeLucaAlberton  could you please help to show where the location of Runner.xcscheme in Xcode? could you please a screenshot? I have tried to find but I can't. really need your help

Comment: @Alexa289 It would be easier for you if you opened your project search and searched for `LaunchAction`, it would take you right to it. But here it is: `/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme`
The reason you can't find it is because it's not a loose file, it's inside your project's .xcodeproj file. Damn Apple with their files that contain files.

Comment: This saved me. Only needed to change the buildConfiguration to debug.

Comment: Thanks, this comments help me to run project on Xcode 14.3

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.
After doing `flutter upgrade` (from version 3.7.9 to 3.7.10) it worked again.

Comment: Nice, it worked for me too. I was in version 3.7.7 and now at version 3.7.11 builds without any warning/error message.
Note: I also made the modification in Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh file as suggested by Bm Mn in the above answer with Flutter version 3.7.7 and did not work. Maybe this two answers together is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I changed my build configuration from release to debug mode, and it builds successfully.

You can change the build configuration from Xcode. Go to the product tap, and then *scheme*. Edit the scheme and change it in a drop down menu to debug.

Comment: hi Kiumars, could you please add a screenshot about this? it would really really help me as a non expert developer :)

Comment: If you don't mind editing de file directly, the answer lies in my comment on one of the posts above.
Path of the file that contains the `debugConfiguration` variable: `/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme`

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade Flutter to 3.7.12 and then change the build configuration from release to debug mode. After that, the iOS simulator should working.

Thanks to [Kiumars's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75902251/flutter-ios-build-failed-dvtcoredeviceenabledstate-disabled/76083493#76083493).

Comment: hi Kasidit, could you please add a screenshot about this? I mean how to configure from release to debug ? it would really really help me as a non expert developer :)

Comment: please I really need it, I still can't find it

Answer (score 2):

Updating cocoapods to 1.12.1 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had that error, and I did fix it by following these steps:

1. First I removed the Xcode 14.3
2. I downloaded the [Xcode_14.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.2/Xcode_14.2.xip)
3. installed it

Comment: Link to 14.2 seems to now be https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.2/Xcode_14.2.xip

Answer (score 1):

In my case, two ways work for me. The first way is rollback Xcode (14.3) to (14.2). The second way is upgrade Flutter to 3.7.12 and then open the *ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh* file. Find this line

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
fi
```

Change it to:

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you get this error if you need to agree to an update of the Program License Agreement (PLA) on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

If you open the app in XCode you will see a red error text about this on the screen where you select the development team. After accepting the license and clicking "Try again..." in XCode, it compiled normally in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Updating CocoaPods, Xcode, and Flutter to the latest versions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could build iOS app in **Xcode**, and it will give you more specific reason about the error.

In my case, the reason is that ruby language's method name is changed.

[image]

I fixed the error by modifying from `exists` to `exist` in **ReadDotEnv.rb**.
(.../ios/.symlinks/plugins/flutter_config/ios/Classes/ReadDotEnv.rb)

```rb
  if File.exist?("#{envs_root}../.envfile")
    envFilePath = "#{envs_root}../.envfile"
  elsif File.exist?("#{envs_root}/.envfile")
    envFilePath = "#{envs_root}.envfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I change channel to master and run `flutter upgrade`. And rechange to `stable channel` and run `flutter upgrade` again. After that, my build work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by upgrading your Flutter version. Here is a change log to the official fix for Xcode 14.3.

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was at Flutter version 3.7.1 and upgrading to 3.7.12 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

check if your pods install correctly, this can happen if you forget to install pods for your ios app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this suggestion works for me:

In the podfile file...

Replace

```
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
   end
 end
```

With

```
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
     end
   end
 end
```

and change Supported Platforms to this [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me who uses Flavors, but it should also work for non-Flavor projects, the following error is:
**ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/EXAMPLE.xcscheme**

On line 28 and 29 (in my project, I look for the corresponding one in yours)

Change from:

```
selectedDebuggerIdentifier = ""
selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn"
```

For:

```
selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB"
selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Launcher.LLDB"
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
flutter clean
```

Or build clean from Xcode will work.

Comment: In what context? From the command line? Wouldn't that result in `Command 'Flutter' not found`?

Comment: If you are getting command not found, the path to flutter is not setup properly
Go through this or flutter official website
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071/flutter-command-not-found

Comment: No, you missspelled the command...

Answer (score -1):

This issue happens because you updated Xcode to version 14.3

To fix this issue you have to upgrade flutter to version 3.7.1 via this command:

```
$ cd flutter
$ git checkout 3.7.1
$ flutter build ipa
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue happened to me when creating a release version and running on the physical device via Xcode.

In the runner scheme settings make sure you have "build configuration" set to "debug"