# DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, runtime-error

I go this bug when trying to run a flutter app with an iOS simulator running iOS 16.4 on a 14 pro Mac if that's relevant. I updated all of flutter and its dependencies multiple times. I originally had an issue with coco pods but I resolved that and this error started to show up. I already went through this post ([Flutter iOS build failed: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75902251/flutter-ios-build-failed-dvtcoredeviceenabledstate-disabled)) but the solution did not fix my issue.

Here's is the entire error for more detail:

Error output from Xcode build:

```
↳
    2023-07-14 17:22:11.968 xcodebuild[46080:2606515] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    2023-07-14 17:22:12.109 xcodebuild[46080:2606515] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in
    /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-21815/IDEFoundation/Execution/Schemes/IDE
    Scheme.m:496
    Details:  ignoring attempt to mark as dirty as scheme that has a load error
    Object:   <IDEScheme: 0x132e6d610>
    Method:   -markSchemeDirtyFromUserChange
    Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x6000033a8240>{number = 1, name = main}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    xcodebuild: error: Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action.
```