# MySQLClient instal error: "raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to install mysqlclient to my Python 3.6. Originally what i want to install is MySQLdb, however it was saying that MySQLdb does not work with Python 3 (still?). So i switch to mysqlclient.

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

However, it was given this error:

```
    Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/h3/sff7td1d6pg5v5qsm5xf31q80000gn/T/pip-install-ki9z7ln9/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/h3/sff7td1d6pg5v5qsm5xf31q80000gn/T/pip-install-ki9z7ln9/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 60, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/h3/sff7td1d6pg5v5qsm5xf31q80000gn/T/pip-install-ki9z7ln9/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 60, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/h3/sff7td1d6pg5v5qsm5xf31q80000gn/T/pip-install-ki9z7ln9/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 13, in dequote
        raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?")
    Exception: Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?
```

Can I know what should i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a bug since November 2017.
I had the same error and that's what helped:

1. Make changes to `mysql_config` file in mysqlclient-python or mysql-connector-c or libmysqlclient (depending on what you are using)

   Change

```
    # on macOS, on or about line 112:
    # Create options
    libs="-L$pkglibdir"
    libs="$libs -l "
```

to:

```
    # Create options
    libs="-L$pkglibdir"
    libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

2. Add following to the end of your `.bash_profile` [how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30462883/9631956):

```
   export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

3. Run `pip install mysqlclient`, that should work now.

For more info check  [this link](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/), look at the "Note about bug of MySQL Connector/C on macOS" section.

Comment: Wow. Spent 3 hours on this and a number of issues related to it. This worked for me. I had to also use the legacy password system of MySQL in MacOS.

Comment: I have mamp on my computer also, and I initially found the `mysql_config` there, which is nothing like the one you need to edit. The solution is to run `which mysql_config` from the terminal, which will give you a path. I suspect this may also depend on if you are using a virtual environment.

Comment: I found `mysql_config` at `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`, `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/5.7.23/bin/mysql_config`, 
`/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/bin/mysql_config`, 
`/opt/anaconda3/bin/mysql_config`, and
`/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-h42c63d9_1003/bin/mysql_config` using `find / -name mysql_config -type f`. I have used `conda` and `brew` to install mysql clients. Once I made sure these all had these compile options, everything worked!