# ommand "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/tt/qgg159gx5g9_rqh58q0ctdxr0000gn/T/pip-install-uLT44i/mysqlclient/

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

How could I solve this problem?

I just run below cmd

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Output:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/a2/1230ebbb4b91f42ad6b646e59eb8855559817ad5505d81c1ca2b5a216040/mysqlclient-1.3.14.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/tt/qgg159gx5g9_rqh58q0ctdxr0000gn/T/pip-install-kuVn0W/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 60, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 13, in dequote
        raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?")
    Exception: Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?
```

Following command:

```
python setup.py egg_info
```

failed with error:

```
code 1 in /private/var/folders/tt/qgg159gx5g9_rqh58q0ctdxr0000gn/T/pip-install-kuVn0W/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQLClient instal error: "raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578425/mysqlclient-instal-error-raise-exceptionwrong-mysql-configuration-maybe-htt)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-python%5D+Exception%3A+Wrong+MySQL+configuration