# Unable to install SASS - can't find .bash_profile file on Mac OS

Tags: macos, sass

I'm trying to install SASS on Mac as per the official instructions here https://sass-lang.com/install

I downloaded the package from GitHub but can't find the `.bash_profile` file anywhere in my home directory.

When I try the other available option and run
`npm install -g sass` I get an error that 'The operation was rejected by your operating system'

Can someone please instruct me how to find the `.bash_profile` file or how to install it in general?

Answer (score 1):

For your .bash_profile issue you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-os-x).
And for the operating system rejection message, that means current user might not have permission to access npm file, try running your commands with sudo

```
sudo npm install -g sass
```