# Cannot connect to mySQL v5.6.26 on Mac OS 10.10.5. after several days

Tags: mysql, database, macos, connection, database-connection

I installed MySQL 2 yrs ago without any issues on Mac. But now I got new Mac and I cannot connect to newly installed db. This is extremely frustrating as I am trying now for DAYS to solve the problem.

Here is what I did:

1. Went to: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/
2. Downloaded: MySQL Workbench (GPL) Release 6.3.4
3. I didn't know whether that installed MySQL server, since nowhere is it clearly stated that the package "includes MySQL server"...so
4. I also installed MySQL Community Server (GPL): 5.6.26
5. On My Mac I went to "system preferences" the MySQL icon was visible. Clicked on MySQL icon -> message states "The MYSQL Server Instance IS RUNNING"
6. I opened up my workbench and tried to connect to db using hostname:127.0.0.1, Port:3306, Username:root, Password [none]. Then I click on "Test Connection" and I get error message...

> "**Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root Can't
>   connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)**"

What is happening? Why cannot I connect to db?

When I go to command prompt and enter mysql, it doesn't recognize command.

When I type in export `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/` and then mysql command, the mysql command returns its typical language "Welcome to the MySQL monitor.....etc"

**Can someone explain why I cannot connect to the database using Workbench? (I also cannot connect using Navicat)**

**I NEVER remember having such issues when I was installing MySql 2 years ago.**

Comment: you did have an issue if my memory [serves](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19462438/1816093). How did you resolve it then?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, and was able to solve it by changing the port to 3307. I only tried this after *much* searching, and I saw this post (https://superuser.com/questions/972276/mysql-binds-to-port-3307-not-port-3306), so I tried it and it just fixed everything..